# KVL and KCL in MOSFET small-signal model, how?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis

I want to find the gain in this MOSFET small-signal model.

KVL in loop 1:

\$+V_{in}-V_{gs}-g_mV_{gs}R_s=0 \iff V_{in}=V_{gs}(1+g_mR_s)\$

KVL in loop 2:

\$+V_{out}-g_mV_{gs}R_s=0 \iff V_{out}=g_mV_{gs}R_s\$

**Questions:**

In the answer \$V_{out}\$ should have a negative sign,  \$V_{out}=-g_mR_s \cdot V_{in}\$. What have I missed?

The final answer is \$V_{out} / V_{in}=-g_mR_d/(1+g_mR_s)\$. (*)

How can the current through \$R_d\$ be \$g_mV_{gs}\$? Shouln't there instead be a KCL in \$V_a\$, so the current through \$R_d\$ is \$V_{out}/R_d\$?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDCR2S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Update with KCL in \$V_a\$:**

\$I_{out}-i_d-I_r=0\$

where \$i_d=g_mV_{gs}\$ and \$I_r=V_{out}/R_d\$, so

\$I_{out}=g_mV_{gs}+V_{out}/R_d\$.

I'm stuck here, how can I find equation (*) above?

Comment: Your KVL loop2 is incorrect, Vout is not gm*Vgs*Rs, you made Vs = Vout. You should not use a voltage loop as there's a current source (gmVgs) in the loop. Use the current law instead and make sure Rd is in the expression because it is **crucial**. The overall transfer (Vout/Vin) will have a negative sign and both Rs and Rd must be in the expression.

Comment: Where is Iout going? (Is there a loop there)?

Answer (score 1):

KVL in loop 2 is missing the voltage across the current source. Because that's an unknown, instead combine your KCL expression with your KVL loop 1 expression:

$$
V_{in} = V_{gs}(1+g_mR_s)
\\
I_{out} = g_mV_{gs}+V_{out}/R_d \implies V_{out} = (I_{out} - g_mV_{gs})R_d
\\
\therefore \frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}=\frac{I_{out}R_d - g_mV_{gs}R_d}{V_{gs}(1+g_mR_s)}=\frac{I_{out}R_d/V_{gs} - g_mR_d}{1+g_mR_s}
$$

Now if and only if \$I_{out} = 0\$, the expression reduces to:

$$
\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}=\frac{-g_mR_d}{1+g_mR_s}
$$

which is the result you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Donsert you can find the solution in the following figure

[image]